# AddJoin failing in Python ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-000840

My AddJoin operation is failing:

```
arcpy.CopyRows_management(lup_file,out_dir+'lup')
try:
    # Perform copy rows on merged csv file
    print 'start'
    aa = arcpy.Raster(SEIMF)
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(aa, "VALUE", out_dir+'lup', "VALUE", "KEEP_ALL")
    print 'end'
    #arcpy.AddJoin_management(gis_dir+SIF, "VALUE", out_dir+'lup', "VALUE", "KEEP_ALL")
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

error messages:

> Executing: AddJoin C:\Users\Documents\Projects\AB\Inputs\gis\sif VALUE C:\Users\Documents\Projects\AB\Outputs\C\output\lup VALUE KEEP_ALL
>   Start Time: Sat Feb 22 02:27:50 2014
>   Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000840: The value is not a Table View.
>   ERROR 000825: The value is not a layer or table view
>   ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer.
>   ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
>   WARNING 000970: The join field VALUE in the join table sif is not indexed. To improve performance, we recommend that an index be created for the join field in the join table.
>   Failed to execute (AddJoin).

Does anyone know what is happening? I get this error only in the python code and can execute AddJoin just fine if I use the ArcGIS manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arcpy.AddJoin_management` request a layer or a table view, and you are feeding a raster dataset, which is not exactly the same.

Instead of `arcpy.Raster`, use [`arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//00170000006t000000). Also make sure that your layer has an attribute table (`arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management`), but his does not seem to be the problem in your case.

Comment: Thanks so much! The error is gone. However, when I open the raster in ArcGIS, I do not see any new joined columns. Any ideas on why this might be? I have checked that the table I am joining is not empty.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't saving the temporary layer. Works now after I save it using SaveToLayerFile_management. Thank you so much again!